# W3 CSS Validation | Value error for gradients

Tags: css

While using the [W3 CSS validator](http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/validator) i get this error

> Value Error : background linear-gradient(top,#fefefe,#dddddd) is not a
>   background-color value : linear-gradient(top,#fefefe,#dddddd)

for this line:

```
  background:  linear-gradient(top, #fefefe, #dddddd);
```

as well as:

```
  background:  -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #fefefe, #dddddd);
```

and other lines when I try to use gradient.

The gradients works, but am I using the wrong syntax?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

CSS3 has not been finalized yet, meaning the validator is likely not validating against the latest working draft of CSS3. Also, the validator will probably not validate vendor specific css like -moz-* or -webkit-*

see the [most recent draft](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css3-images/#linear-gradients) from w3 for the specification on using linear gradients.

BTW, I believe "top" in your code should be "to top" as the direction of the gradient. Example 12 from the draft:

> Below are various ways of specifying a basic vertical gradient:
>
> ```
> linear-gradient(yellow, blue);
> linear-gradient(to bottom, yellow, blue);
> linear-gradient(180deg, yellow, blue);
> linear-gradient(to top, blue, yellow);
> linear-gradient(to bottom, yellow 0%, blue 100%);
> ```

Comment: It was actually `top` a very long time ago.

Answer (score 1):

What version of CSS are you choosing on the validator? Is it set to CSS3? I've known the validator to throw weird errors when in fact there was nothing wrong with my code.

Comment: Did you figure out why...does a bug need to be filed to W3?

Answer (score 1):

Try the following generator:

http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/

This will give you the correct syntax for all browsers.

Answer (score 1):

The w3c's validator uses the recommendations of the w3c. `linear-gradient` has not become a recommendation from the w3c, and therefore it is not technically "valid". The other browser vendors have went ahead and implemented what is specified in the working draft (hoping that it won't change much from now until when the w3c finalizes the specification). This is why you need the vendor prefixes for it to work.

Answer (score 1):

As long as gradients are not part of a final specification, the w3c validator will throw an error for this. don't rely on the validator for "experimental" features in draft state.

so, you're fine with your syntax, but beware of different implementations in browsers.

Comment: so how am I suppose to validate my code effectively...one would think there would be an option for this?

Comment: You may use a preprocessor like [Sass](http://sass-lang.com). It prevents you from writing bad syntax, as it parses (validates) your code before rendering.

Answer (score 0):

Value Error : width Parse Error - 90px)

width: calc(100% - 90px); width: -moz-calc(100% - 90px); width: -webkit-calc(100% - 90px);

Comment: Could you explain how this answers the original question?